# iOS remote controll

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm developing an application for iPad, which works in this way:
I have 3 devices and if i tap a button on one of them the others can handle this event in real time! 
 I try bonjour, but cant not solve that the sender device send datas both of receivers  
 Any suggestion? 
 Many thank

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "not solve that the sender device send datas both of receivers".  Please describe what you're doing, what is happening, and what you **want** to have happen.

Comment: ok: so if I tap the screen i'd like my other 2 devices play a movie. and i try to use bonjour, but sadly i can communicate only one device and not more

Answer (score 0):

My thought is you could put up a simple web service to do this, and have each device hook into the web service. I'd recommend looking into a realtime framework like [Pusher](http://pusher.com/). You could write your own (using polling), but something like Pusher should save you time. They offer an iOS library ([docs](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries)) and it isn't too difficult to integrate.

Comment: Thank U for answer, and i'll check it, but i really would like to know how i can send data to more devices with bonjour or udp! and actually i am new so an example would be great!

Comment: sadly it is not so fast, i'd request